# Php for nested loop for table creation <tr>

Tags: php, loops

please someone can guide me to write nested loop like this in php for loop

output:

```
<tr>
1
2
3
4
5
6
</tr>
<tr>
7
8
9
10
11
12
</tr>

for ($a=0; $a < 10; $a++) { 
        echo $a;
    }
```

Comment: What issues have you encountered when you attempted to solve this problem? Please update question with explanation. Likely should look at `modulo operator`. You also should have a `td` or multiple `td`s if multiple cells are expected.

Comment: i am creating table like
[123456]
[789101112]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like that:

```
<?php
echo "<table>\n";
echo "  <tr>\n";
foreach (range(1, 12) as $i) {
  if ($i>1 && ($i-1) % 6 == 0) {
    echo "  </tr>\n  <tr>\n";
  }
  echo "    <td>$i</td>\n";
}
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
```

Another approach would be to chunk a given set:

```
<?php
$set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

echo "<table>\n";
foreach (array_chunk($set, 6) as $chunk) {
  echo "  <tr>\n";
  foreach ($chunk as $number) {
    echo "    <td>$number</td>\n";
  }
  echo "  </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

The output obviously is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```